# Block the check event of one (or more) checkboxes that do not have a specific attribute value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page I can have 1 or more forms, in each of them I could have checkboxes whose ID is identical, the value of an attribute changes, when clicking on a checkbox there are no problems and the function connected to the check works correctly, but if I click on another checkbox, the previously active one is deactivated

For Example

```
    <div>
    <form class="form-inline" data-id="45677-ff">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="pic-container">
                <label>
                    <span><input type="checkbox" id="clickable" data-id="45677-ff">Merge</span><br>
                 </label>
            </div>
<div class="box hidden" id="45677-ff"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <form class="form-inline" data-id="46g677-ee">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <div class="pic-container">
                <label>
                    <span><input type="checkbox" id="clickable" data-id="46g677-ee">Merge</span><br>
                 </label>
            </div>
<div class="box hidden" id="46g677-ee"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

This is javascript

```
$(document).on("click","#clickable",function(this) {
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    if(checked){
     //some code to hide and activate the div with value of id equal to the 
       //data-id attribute of the checkbox
    }
});
```

There is a way to ensure that when you click on a checkbox, block the event (or not execute the function) for all checkboxes that do not have data-id = the value of the clicked checkbox (retrieved from the id of its form with the closest method perhaps)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your problem is here...
Be aware that the value of the id attribute must be unique within the HTML document. So your `id="clickable"` needs to be `class="clickable"`

In the example below in pure javascript works correctly : you can select the two checkboxes

```js
function CheckBoxClickedEvent(event) {
  if (event.target.type == "checkbox") {
    let elementId = event.target.getAttribute("data-id");
    if (event.target.checked) {
      document.getElementById(elementId).classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
      document.getElementById(elementId).classList.add("hidden");
    }
  }
}


const clickableElements = document.querySelectorAll('.clickable');

clickableElements.forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', CheckBoxClickedEvent);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="form-inline" data-id="45677-ff">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="pic-container">
        <label>
          <span>
            <input type="checkbox" class="clickable" data-id="45677-ff">Merge
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="box hidden" id="45677-ff"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <form class="form-inline" data-id="46g677-ee">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="pic-container">
        <label>
          <span>
            <input type="checkbox" class="clickable" data-id="46g677-ee">Merge
          </span>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="box hidden" id="46g677-ee"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[image: Snippet in action]

Comment: It doesn't work, if I click an unchecked checkbox, it deactivates the active one in the first form, elementId is the same for all checkboxes and I don't understand how it's possible

Comment: I added a gif to my post, where you can see that everything is working correctly.
Make a working example with your code that illustrates your problem if it doesn't work on your page. See here how to make a snippet https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/9947331

Comment: In const clickableElements  I have correctly two element with this id, but when CheckBoxClickedEvent is triggered in  elementId  there are always the id of first element, in my js file I initialize the const e the addListener in $(document).ready(function () {});

Comment: Add a complete example of your code including your code for "activate and deactivate" a div which illustrates your problem without which I will not be able to help you further

Comment: It's a bit complicated, because there's model view model, partial and things that aren't mine in the middle, I should clean up the code a bit, I'll try to see what I can do

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/f08x4c3b/ there are my code

Comment: This doesn't work because you put ```data-id``` for your second hidden box instead of ```id```